# Unity gradle build failed to transform aar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity gradle build fail with error. How can i fix it?

I use

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true
```

Build fail with error:

Failed to transform '...\Temp\gradleOut\libs\com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

That's my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <packages>
    <package>com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.+</package>
    <package>com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.+</package>
    <package>com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1</package>
    <package>com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.9.62</package>
    <package>com.sglib.easymobile:easy-mobile:1.+</package>
  </packages>
  <files>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.core.common-1.0.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.common-1.0.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.asynclayoutinflater.asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.coordinatorlayout.coordinatorlayout-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.core.core-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.cursoradapter.cursoradapter-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.customview.customview-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.documentfile.documentfile-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.drawerlayout.drawerlayout-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.fragment.fragment-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.interpolator.interpolator-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.localbroadcastmanager.localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.print.print-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.slidingpanelayout.slidingpanelayout-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.swiperefreshlayout.swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.versionedparcelable.versionedparcelable-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/androidx.viewpager.viewpager-1.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-annotations-26.1.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-26.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-18.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-base-18.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-18.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-16.0.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-api-phone-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-base-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-16.0.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-drive-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-games-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-18.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-api-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-nearby-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-stats-17.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-16.0.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.games.gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.62.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.sglib.easymobile.easy-mobile-1.2.0.aar</file>
  </files>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: were you able to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have update Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin and problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Try using the newest SDK version in build.gradle

Ex:
compileSdkVersion 29